# Apply opacity to a SVG

Tags: svg, opacity

There are the fill-opacity and stroke-opacity properties but both transparencies overlap and thus the opacity of my stroke is more important. How delete this overlap (with different opacity)?

```
mysvg
.attr('fill', 'rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3)')
.attr('stroke-width', '30px')
.attr('stroke', 'rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6)');
```

I haven't 10 reputation...
[See the result here](http://hpics.li/a9ce1a9)

Comment: Please restate your question with a screenshot or sample code - it's not clear what's being asked and that's why you are being downvoted.

Comment: That's half the story. What do you want it to look like is the other half.

Comment: I think he doesn't want the stroke to overlap the fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what I *think* you want. The easiest is to just draw two shapes - a solid shape shrunk by the stroke width, and then a zero-fill shape with the stroke on top.

However, since you're using the same color for both, it's easy to use a filter to get what you want.

```
<filter id="opacityceiling">
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0.3 0.6"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

This clamps any opacity between 0  and .5 to 0.3, and any opacity between 0.5 and 1.0 to 0.6.  A more general way for different colors would be to use an feFlood and an feComposite.